# Linking to ID of div starts below top of div?

Tags: css, html, href

I've got a div that I'm linking to via 'href="#divId"' and instead of linking to the top of the div it goes down about 100 pixels.  I know that it is starting below the top of the div because the div has a background which extends above where the page links to.  Is this a known problem?

```
    #homepage_aboutstrip {
        background:url('home/images/gradient-about-background.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-size: auto 100%;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:200px;
        width:100%;
        height:1050px;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

Comment: 'Is this a known problem?' - no, it isn't. Show us code of the style of a div =)

Comment: Alright, I updated it. =)

Comment: It might be easier if you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for it.

Comment: I can repo the problem with the above css on either IE 9 or Chrome.  Is it possible it just looks like the div starts above where the link takes you?  try putting a border on the div to see exactly where the edges of the div are:

Comment: I already tried borders in addition to the aforementioned background, and yes, that's what's happening. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code in IE10, IE9, FF, and Chrome and no 100px funny business...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
             #homepage_aboutstrip {
               background:url('home/images/gradient-about-background.png');
               background-repeat:repeat-x;
               background-size: auto 100%;
               position:absolute;
               margin-top:200px;
               width:100%;
               height:1050px;
               z-index:1;
               border:1px solid red; /*threw this in to see if the border aligned w/text, and it does*/
               }
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
    <a style="clear:both;" href="#homepage_aboutstrip">ABOUT STRIP</a>

    <div style="height:500px;">
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 
    </div>

    <div id="homepage_aboutstrip">
    II - The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The only different variable from my code to yours is that I don't have the gradient-about-background.png in my code. There could be a size issue with the .png that's not being taken into account in the css.

Comment: Alright, seems there's something odd going on.  Thanks, mate!